# Automating Folder creation in Azure Data Lake Store (Gen2)

Tags: azure-storage, azure-automation

Is there any way we can automate Folder creations in ADLS Gen2 pragmatically. It is required for doing this in Production Subscription on which there is limited access from Portal.

If there is any suggestions, please help on this.

Comment: You can use the rest api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create)

Answer (score 0):

*For the benefit of broader audience re-sharing Ivan Yang's comment as answer i.e.,.*

You can use the rest api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure cli for this, but it is still in preview.

```
#add the extension
az extension add --name storage-preview 

# Create Directory   
$dirCheck = az storage blob directory exists -c $filesystemName -d $dirname     --account-name $storageaccountname --debug
$exists = $dirCheck | ConvertFrom-Json
If (-Not $exists.exists[0])
{
    az storage blob directory create -c $filesystemName -d $dirname --account-name $storageaccountname 
}
```